# How can I extend a set with a tuple?

Tags: python, set

Unlike `list.extend(L)`, there is no `extend` function in `set`. How can I extend a tuple to a set in pythonic way?

```
t1 = (1, 2, 3)
t2 = (3, 4, 5)
t3 = (5, 6, 7)

s = set()
s.add(t1)
s.add(t2)
s.add(t3)

print s
set([(3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7), (1, 2, 3)])
```

My expected result is:

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

My solutions is something like:

```
for item in t1 :
    s.add(item)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the `union` method -

```
t1 = (1, 2, 3)
t2 = (3, 4, 5)
t3 = (5, 6, 7)
s= set()
s = s.union(t1)
s = s.union(t2)
s = s.union(t3)
s
>>> set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Or as indicated in the comments , cleaner method -

```
s = set().union(t1, t2, t3)
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `set().union(t1, t2, t3)` is even cleaner, IMHO, because of the symmetry among the arguments.

Comment: The documentation of `union` states `Return the union of sets as a new set`, so it seems to only be defined for `set` arguments. Do we know that feeding tuples won't result in undefined behavior in the future?

Comment: Or (arguably) `s = set().union(t1, t2, t3)` or just `s = set(t1 + t2 + t3)`.

Comment: @goncalopp *"Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(), difference(), and symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset() methods will accept any iterable as an argument."* - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset (and in the 2.x version)

Comment: @DSM I begrudge the two additional characters, but it is cleaner conceptually!

Comment: what is the difference between `update` and `union`?

Comment: @SparkandShine `update` is in-place (and therefore only works on `set`, not `frozenset`), whereas `union` returns a new `set`

Answer (score 11):

Either:

```
>>> newSet = s.union(t1, t2, t3)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Or the following, which actually updates without any assignation needed

```
>>> s.update( t1, t2, t3)
>>> s
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Comment: The second one is closer to the original question, which asked for a `extend()` equivalent, thus adding elements to an _existing_ `set`.

Answer (score 9):

You are using the wrong method. `add` adds a single item, `update` unions the set with the argument.

```
t1 = (1, 2, 3)
t2 = (3, 4, 5)
t3 = (5, 6, 7)

s = set()
s.update(t1)
s.update(t2)
s.update(t3)

print s
```

Comment: You only need one call to `update`, which can accept multiple iterables to add to the set. (`s.update(t1, t2, t3)`)

Comment: @chepner True, although I wanted to show the symmetry with the poster's code

Comment: @vogomatix I didn't scroll down far enough to see your answer :)

Comment: @chepner: don't worry I didn't see DSM's comment either. :)